# Bootstrap Typeahead is keeping the value input

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap typeahead lib in my Angular app.
the app contain a search component with input that used for two other components that are switchable between each other.

I use this logic for the autocomplete term:

```
search = (text$: Observable<string>) =>
    text$.pipe(
        debounceTime(200),
        distinctUntilChanged(),
        map(term => term.length < 1 ? []
            : words.filter(v => v.toLowerCase().indexOf(term.toLowerCase()) > -1).slice(0, 10))
    )
```

and it's work good. The problem is when i'm switching (even if I delete the input value) between the components the search term is keep in the input value.

**For example**: i'm searching for the word 'table' -> getting the results and everything is fine. next I'm trying to switch to the other component (same behavior as the previous one) and the value input is appearing again even after I reset it.

Comment: can you show the code where you reset it?

Comment: this.searchInput.nativeElement.value = '';